# Удаление одинаковых элементов в списке

Tags: python

Например, у меня есть лист x = [a, a, a, a, f, h, k, k, k, k]. Мне надо сделать, что бы в этом листе было только два a и три k, т.е. удалить лишние похожие элементы, остальные не трогать.
Чтоб было так:
x = [a, a, f, h, k, k, k]

Comment: И как, получилось?

Comment: очень странная задача

Comment: Почему именно 2 a и 3 k, а не скажем 1 a и 1 k, или 3 a и 3 k? :)

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно выбрать уникальные значения из списка, можете воспользоваться этим кодом:

```
def unique_list(items):
    x = []
    for a in items:
        if a not in x:
            x.append(a)
    return x

print(unique_list([1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5]))
# Выйдет: 12345
```

Comment: Зачем мудрить, если то, что вы написали, можно уместить в одной строчке? :) unique_list = set([1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5]). Автор, скорее всего, не это имел ввиду.

Comment: @Glebium, `list` это название встроенное функции [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), поэтому не рекомендует использовать его, отступы лучше всегда использовать одинаковые

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос автора. Ваш код никак не решает проблему получения трёx значений одного типа и двух значений другого.

Answer (score 0):

сделайте словарь с разрешенным количеством повторов символа и проверяйте, то в результате их не больше

```
d = {'a':2, 'k':3}
x = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'f', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'k']
res = []

for i in x :
   if res.count(i) < d.get(i, len(x)) :
      res.append(i)
print(res)
```